# Redirect logged in user to new website with automatic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have one website designed in ASP.NET MVC 5 hosted with website name of `www.oldsite.com`.

We just now started a new website - `www.newsite.com` with some changes to the ASP.NET MVC code and but database is the same for both sites.

When a user logs in to the old website, `www.oldsite.com` verifies the login details (userid and password) and after successful login redirects the user based on some condition to new website `www.newsite.com` with automatic login (user does not need to re-enter userid and password in login page again on `www.newsite.com`) and shows the home page of `www.newsite.com`.

This is my code

```
int timeout = login.RememberMe ? 600 : 60; // 525600 min = 1 year
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(v.PEmailId, login.RememberMe, timeout);

string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
cookie.HttpOnly = true;                        

Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                 
if (some condition)
{
    return Redirect("www.newsite.com");
}
```

I need some login authentication cookies code, I am using ASP.NET identity.

Please tell me how to redirect from old site to new site `www.newsite.com` with login credentials (give like userid and password parameter in login page and automatically login into new website) or how to create cookies for new website `www.newsite.com` for automatic login without entering userid and password.

Thank you

Comment: You could pass a session token as a url parameter (or form post) to the new site and autologin. But what happens the next time the user needs to login? Are they going to keep going to oldsite? What impact is there going to be with the way they store passwords...

Answer (score 0):

From old site you can pass the username and password as parameter.

```
return Redirect(string.Format("https://newsite.com/Home/Index?username={0}&password={1}","username", "password"));
```

In new site create a function that allow anonymous users. Then validate the user credential. If the user is valid one then add cookies and redirect to the page you want.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string username, string password)
    {
        // validate the user credential
        // add cookie
        User user = new User();
        user.UserName = username;
        user.Password = password;
        AddCookie(user);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }

    public void AddCookie(User user)
    {
        string encryptTicket, userData;
        HttpCookie httpCookie = null;
        try
        {
            userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                1, user.UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), true, userData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            encryptTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            httpCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(httpCookie);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }
        return httpCookie;
    }
}

public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Small nitpick: you should never pass sensitive information through a query string as that information can be cached in the user's browser or other internet appliances, logs, etc.